# Rx flatMapLatest doesn't pass completed through?

Tags: system.reactive, rx-swift

I expected to see `timer -> Event completed` get outputted right after I saw `running -> Event completed` but it didn't happen.

Can someone explain why and give me some idea on how to complete the `timer` observable?

```
/// playground

import RxSwift
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


struct TimerCountdown {

    let timer: Observable<Int>

    init(running: Observable<Bool>) {
        timer = running.flatMapLatest { $0 ? Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) : Observable<Int>.never() }
    }

}

let running = PublishSubject<Bool>()
let countdown = TimerCountdown(running: running)

_ = running.debug("running").subscribe()

_ = countdown.timer.debug("timer").subscribe()

running.onNext(true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
    running.onNext(false)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7.5) {
    running.onNext(true)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.5) {
    running.onCompleted()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
struct TimerCountdown {

    let timer: Observable<Int>

    init(running: Observable<Bool>) {
        timer = running
            .flatMapLatest { $0 ? Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) : Observable<Int>.never() }
            .takeUntil(running.materialize().filter { $0.isCompleted })
    }
}
```

---

Here's another answer that doesn't require subscribing to `running` twice:

```
struct TimerCountdown {

    let timer: Observable<Int>

    init(running: Observable<Bool>) {
        timer = running.materialize()
            .flatMapLatest { (event) -> Observable<Int> in
                switch event {
                case let .next(value):
                    return value ? Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) : Observable.never()
                case .completed:
                    return Observable.empty()
                case let .error(error):
                    return Observable.error(error)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a way to pass the completed to the flatmaplatest

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative way if subscribing to the Observable<Bool> twice is an issue for you.